# Equation for the normal derivative of the solution of Poisson's equation

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

The solution of Poisson's equation 
\begin{align*}
\Delta u  &= 0 ~~~\text{in } B_r \\
u &= g~~~\text{in } \partial B_r,
\end{align*}
is well known. For some $a\in\Bbb R\setminus \{0\}$ we have
$$
u(x) = \frac{r^2-|x|^2}{a} \int_{\partial B_r} \frac{g(y)}{|x-y|^n}dS(y).
$$
Does there exist a constant $c\in\mathbb{R}^+$  such that 
$$\partial_\nu u = c\, u~~~\text{in }\partial B_r\,?$$

Comment: Is it $\partial\Omega=\partial B_r$ or you are asking if the relation $\partial_\nu u=cu$ holds for every general domain $\Omega$?

Comment: you are right it is $\partial B_r = \partial \Omega$ I corrected it